# WrongClassException when trying to implement Strategy Pattern (discriminating on own Id)

Tags: c#, nhibernate, design-patterns, fluent-nhibernate

I'm trying to implement the Strategy Pattern with Fluent Nhibernate, inspired by [this blog post](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2008/08/27/strategies-and-discriminators-in-nhibernate/)

```
public abstract class Strategy
{
    protected Strategy() { }
    protected Strategy(Guid id) { this.Id = id; }
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public abstract void SomeMethod();
}

public class MyStrategy : Strategy
{
    public MyStrategy() : base(new Guid("F1CF041B ...")) { }
    public override void SomeMethod() { }
}

public class StrategyMap : ClassMap<Strategy>
{
    public StrategyMap()
    {
        this.Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Assigned();
        this.DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn("Id");
    }
}

public class MyStrategyMap : SubclassMap<MyStrategy>
{
    public MyStrategyMap()
    {
        this.DiscriminatorValue("F1CF041B ...");
    }
}
```

But when I run the following test (where `this.Session` is from a in-memory-database):

```
[TestMethod]
public void CanGetMyStrategy()
{
    // Arrange
    using (var transaction = this.Session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        this.Session.Save(new MyStrategy());
        transaction.Commit();
        this.Session.Clear();
    }

    // Act
    var strategies = this.Session.Query<Strategy>();

    // Assert
    Assert.IsNotNull(strategies.FirstOrDefault());
}
```

The following exception is thrown:

```
NHibernate.WrongClassException: 
  Object with id: f1cf041b ... 
  was not of the specified subclass: Namespace.Strategy 
  (Discriminator was: 'f1cf041b ...')
```

Any help debugging this issue would be appreciated as I can't figure out why this doesn't work.

---

#### Unsatifactory solution

I can get the code to work by not discriminating on the Id column (and so creating another column to discriminate on), but I find this unsatisfactory as it means duplicating data.

---

#### Why Guid?

The reasoning behind this is that new `Strategy`s will be able to be created via a plugin architecture (providing an implementation of `Strategy` and `SubclassMap<[strategy-name]>` which get read at application load), and as such I need to use `Guid`s so there aren't conflicts with Ids.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that in *Strategy* class you are using `Id` of type `Guid`
but in mapper class `string` instead of `Guid` is used.

I changed map class as described below, and exception ceased to appear

```
public class MyStrategyMap : SubclassMap<MyStrategy>
{
    public MyStrategyMap()
    {
        this.DiscriminatorValue(new Guid("F1CF041B ..."));
    }
}
```

Comment: +50: All green! Can't believe I missed that. Thanks!