# Factory-like pattern without manually writing discriminator into Factory

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have the following:

```
public abstract class FooBase
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Foo1 : FooBase { /* could be stuff here */ }

public class Foo2 : FooBase { /* could be stuff here */ }

public class Bar
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual SOMETHING WhichFoo { get; set } 
}
```

...where `WhichFoo` deals with which `FooBase` to use (potentially `string` of `"Foo1"` but this seems quite messy).

With mappings:

```
public class FooBaseMap : ClassMap<FooBase>
{
    public FooBaseMap()
    {
        this.Id(x => x.Id);
        this.DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn("Type");
    }
}

public class Foo1Map : SubclassMap<Foo1>
{
    public Foo1Map() { this.DiscriminatorValue("Foo1"); }
}

public class Foo2Map : SubclassMap<Foo2>
{
    public Foo2Map() { this.DiscriminatorValue("Foo2"); }
}
```

What I want to be able to do is to create a new `Foo`, either 1 or 2, based on a value stored in `Bar`. So:

```
Bar bar = this.Session.Get<Bar>(1);

FooBase foo1 = bar.GetANewFoo(); // returns a new Foo1

Bar anotherBar = this.Session.Get<Bar>(123);

FooBase foo2 = bar.GetANewFoo(); // returns a new Foo2
```

Where `GetANewFoo()` could be a method, a property which returns an empty instance of `Foo1` or `Foo2`.

Effectively what I want to do is to store the type of `FooBase` to be created by `GetANewFoo` in `Bar`.

What's the best way of going about this without explicitly having to **manually** write `"Foo1"` or `"Foo2"` to a `Bar` when I create one?

Comment: how you know if is to create foo1 or foo2?

Comment: @LucasAbilidebob Good point, added a property to `Bar` to deal with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I think I got it - actually [rehashing a method I used for the Strategy Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21403260/wrongclassexception-when-trying-to-implement-strategy-pattern-discriminating-on).

```
public abstract class FooFactoryBase
{
    protected FooFactoryBase() { } // for NHibernate

    protected FooFactoryBase(Guid id)
    {
        this.Id = id;
    }

    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
    public abstract FooBase CreateFoo();
}

public class Foo1Factory : FooFactoryBase
{
    public readonly static Guid Guid = new Guid("abc123...");

    public Foo1Factory() : base(Guid) { }

    public override FooBase CreateFoo()
    {
        return new Foo1();
    }
}
```

Then `Bar` becomes:

```
public class Bar
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual FooFactoryBase FooFactory { get; set; }
}
```

And mappings:

```
public class BarMap : ClassMap<Bar>
{
    this.Id(x => x.Id);
    this.Map(x => x.Name);
    this.References(x => x.FooFactory);
}

public class FooFactoryBaseMap : ClassMap<FooFactoryBase>
{
    this.Id(x => x.Id);
    this.HasMany(x => x.Bars).Inverse();
    this.DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn("Id");
}

public class Foo1FactoryMap : SubClassMap<Foo1Factory>
{
    this.DiscriminatorValue(Foo1Factory.Guid);
}
```

Now when I create my database I can populate it with all my `FooFactory`s, when adding `Bars` I can just load the appropriate `Factory` from the database and then call my code like so:

```
Bar bar = this.Session.Get<Bar>(10);

FooBase foo = bar.FooFactory.CreateFoo();
```

and the appropriate `FooBase` will be created.

Sometimes you just need to ask the question to figure it out :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a column in the Bar table which is going to save what kind of Foo it is. So, if this `SOMETHING` type of property is an `enum`, or a `string`, or an `int` (whatever), you can use `switch-case statement` to identify the kind of Foo, create what you need and return.

Just like this:

```
    public FooBase GetANewFoo()
    {
        switch (WhichFoo)
        {
            case "Foo1": return new Foo1();
            case "Foo2": return new Foo2();
            default: return null;
        }
    }
```